# Antivirus app for MacOS that I can quit

Tags: osx, macos, antivirus

I know there is a number of antivirus solutions for Mac, ranging from complete suites like Norton to just plain antivirus solutions like Avira. But I have not found anything that satisfy my requirements.

My use case is as follows:

I'm offline, not copying any files from unknown flash drives and running Mac on battery and just want to maximize its run time. I would like to quit as many apps as possible. But a few AV solutions that I have tried would not let me quit/exit the app when/if I do not need them at the time. The only solution to unload it from memory is to uninstall the app.

Are there any antivirus solutions for MacOS that I can quit/exit when/if I no longer need it in memory?

Answer (score 3):

There is an app called [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com) that will scan your system for malware and viruses. It is currently very popular with Mac users.  The personal copy is not free. It sales for one device for $3.33 per month or $39.96 per year.  You can start and stop the app whenever you choose.